# Convert files from different paths using Python

Tags: python, excel, loops, csv, path

I´m trying to convert Excel files from different paths but it only converts the file in the last path in path list.

What is the proper way to loop trough the paths in the list to to get the files to be converted?

```
import pandas as pd
import glob, os
import csv, json
import openpyxl
from pathlib import Path


list_path = Path("excel_files/PLM", "excel_files/PTR", "excel_files/TMR")
for xlsx_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(list_path,"*.xlsx*")):
    data_xls = pd.read_excel(xlsx_file, 'Relatório - DADOS', index_col=None, engine = 'openpyxl')
    csv_file = os.path.splitext(xlsx_file)[0]+".csv"
    data_xls.to_csv(csv_file, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Path("excel_files/PLM", "excel_files/PTR", "excel_files/TMR")` returns a single path, not a list of paths:

```py
>>> Path("excel_files/PLM", "excel_files/PTR", "excel_files/TMR")
PosixPath('excel_files/PLM/excel_files/PTR/excel_files/TMR')
```

I'm not sure why it finds any files at all, to be honest.

Instead, you will probably have to do another loop - something like:

```py
for path in ["excel_files/PLM", "excel_files/PTR", "excel_files/TMR"]:
    for xlsx_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xlsx*")):
        ...
```

Comment: Hi @jfschaefer it worked thanks. How can I send the resulting files to the same folder? It now converts each file to the root folder where the excel is, but I need them to be in the same folder but diferent from root.

Comment: I guess you can do something in `data_xls.to_csv(csv_file, ...)`, like `data_xls.to_csv(os.path.join('your_new_root', path, csv_file), ...)`. But it might complain if the folders don't exist.

Comment: Or if you want to in the same folder, `data_xls.to_csv(os.path.join(path, csv_file), ...)` should work

Comment: Hi. He is appending the root path to the save path I have given.  And, Like you said returns an error  "non-existent directory: 'csv_files\excel_files\PLM'"

Comment: you can just create it manually or do in the line before `Path(os.path.join('your_new_root', path, csv_file)).mkdir(exist_ok=True)`

Comment: my dudes (inclusive) stop mixing `pathlib` and `os`. i'm sure it's allowed like mixing peanut butter and horseradish is allowed, but it still weirds people out. you can make new paths by using the slash operator, i.e. `Path("excel_files") / "PLM"`. also `Path.glob` and `Path.rglob` are things too.